# JPA : Do JPA trims the string before it search for id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

here I am pass user_id as `"abc        "` or `"            abc          "`. I am using DB2 . now I have `abc` in the database, but even on adding the space JPA is finding the id successfully and return the object.

do we have any rule on treating the space in JPA.

```
Test test = testRepository.findByUserId(user_id).orElseThrow(
                () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with -> username " + user_id));
```

Comment: Do you use spring data jpa?

Comment: Yes it is sprinf data jpa

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the default behaviour in DB2 when it comes to String comparison. According to the respective documentation in the Section [String comparisons](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008479.html):

> When comparing character strings of unequal lengths, the comparison is made using a logical copy of the shorter string, which is padded on the right with blanks sufficient to extend its length to that of the longer string. This logical extension is done for all character strings, including those tagged as FOR BIT DATA.

If you would like for the whitespaces to not be ignored, you would need to use the LIKE functionality instead.

Comment: So it means I have to change it tofindByUserIdLike